# Mount HDD with multiple partitions

Tags: mount, ext3

I have an external HDD with two partitions. Both are *ext3* partitions and works fine with Linux. When I plug the USB HDD in my Android device, it does not work. I see some errors in `dmesg`:

```
[ 3132.712025] sd 206:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
```

Following is the full log (also available at [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/1yJ8iuBj)):

```
[ 3129.797281] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3129.948997] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=04fc, idProduct=0c25
[ 3129.949076] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[ 3129.949118] usb 1-1: Product: USB to Serial-ATA bridge
[ 3129.949159] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Sunplus Technology Inc.
[ 3129.949195] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: ST3500820A            9QMB89AR
[ 3129.956216] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 3129.956759] scsi206 : usb-storage 1-1:1.0
[ 3130.943497] scsi 206:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ST350082 0AS                   PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[ 3130.947482] sd 206:0:0:0: [sda] 976773168 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/465 GiB)
[ 3130.948602] sd 206:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[ 3130.950308] sd 206:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[ 3130.950387] sd 206:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 38 00 00 00
[ 3130.953130] sd 206:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page found
[ 3130.953203] sd 206:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 3130.961231] sd 206:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page found
[ 3130.961312] sd 206:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 3131.096185] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3131.381492] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3131.676711] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3131.971902] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3132.267086] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3132.562270] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3132.712025] sd 206:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3132.712106] sd 206:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 3132.712140] Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3132.712178] sd 206:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
[ 3132.712205] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 3132.712305] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0
[ 3132.712345] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 0
[ 3132.847682] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3133.142899] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3133.438095] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3133.733289] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3134.028505] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3134.323707] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3134.473244] sd 206:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3134.473324] sd 206:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 3134.473357] Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3134.473396] sd 206:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
[ 3134.473422] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 3134.473518] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0
[ 3134.473558] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 0
[ 3134.609000] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3134.904220] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3135.199424] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3135.494638] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3135.789882] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3136.085081] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3136.234861] sd 206:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3136.234942] sd 206:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 3136.234974] Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3136.235014] sd 206:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
[ 3136.235040] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 3136.235136] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0
[ 3136.235177] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 0
[ 3136.235299]  sda: unable to read partition table
[ 3136.244113] sd 206:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page found
[ 3136.244198] sd 206:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 3136.244248] sd 206:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[ 3136.429360] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3136.724578] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3137.019861] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3137.315036] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3137.610218] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3137.905427] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3138.055309] sd 206:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3138.055385] sd 206:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 3138.055422] Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3138.055459] sd 206:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
[ 3138.055485] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 f0 00
[ 3138.055583] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0
[ 3138.055622] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 0
[ 3138.055684] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 1
[ 3138.055720] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 2
[ 3138.055755] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 3
[ 3138.055790] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 4
[ 3138.055824] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 5
[ 3138.055858] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 6
[ 3138.180976] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3138.466284] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3138.751642] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3139.037079] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3139.332211] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3139.627405] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3139.777006] sd 206:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3139.777088] sd 206:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 3139.777119] Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3139.777162] sd 206:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
[ 3139.777190] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 3139.777288] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0
[ 3139.777323] quiet_error: 23 callbacks suppressed
[ 3139.777358] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 0
[ 3139.962008] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3140.257168] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3140.552444] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3140.847589] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3141.142778] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3141.437970] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3141.587839] sd 206:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3141.587922] sd 206:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 3141.587956] Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3141.587993] sd 206:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
[ 3141.588021] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 f0 00
[ 3141.588121] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0
[ 3141.588162] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 0
[ 3141.588228] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 1
[ 3141.588265] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 2
[ 3141.588300] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 3
[ 3141.588335] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 4
[ 3141.588369] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 5
[ 3141.588405] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 6
[ 3141.588441] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 7
[ 3141.588477] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 8
[ 3141.723340] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3142.008700] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3142.294008] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3142.579457] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3142.874631] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3143.169809] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3143.319518] sd 206:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3143.319599] sd 206:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 3143.319633] Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3143.319672] sd 206:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
[ 3143.319700] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 3143.319798] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0
[ 3143.484670] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3143.799687] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3144.094726] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3144.389973] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3144.685229] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3144.980369] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3145.129772] sd 206:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3145.129809] sd 206:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 3145.129823] Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3145.129840] sd 206:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
[ 3145.129853] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 f0 00
[ 3145.129896] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0
[ 3145.255897] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3145.541259] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3145.826603] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3146.112009] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3146.407167] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3146.702336] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3146.852225] sd 206:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3146.852306] sd 206:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 3146.852338] Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3146.852380] sd 206:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
[ 3146.852407] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 3146.852503] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0
[ 3146.852538] quiet_error: 52 callbacks suppressed
[ 3146.852573] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 0
[ 3147.046747] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3147.341944] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3147.637250] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3147.932432] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3148.227603] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3148.522749] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3148.672173] sd 206:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3148.672213] sd 206:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 3148.672227] Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3148.672243] sd 206:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
[ 3148.672255] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 f0 00
[ 3148.672300] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0
[ 3148.672319] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 0
[ 3148.672350] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 1
[ 3148.672366] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 2
[ 3148.672381] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 3
[ 3148.672396] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 4
[ 3148.672411] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 5
[ 3148.672426] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 6
[ 3148.672440] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 7
[ 3148.672455] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 8
[ 3148.798335] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3149.093531] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3149.388697] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3149.683817] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3149.979098] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3150.274320] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-platform
[ 3150.423545] sd 206:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[ 3150.423576] sd 206:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 3150.423586] Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3150.423597] sd 206:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
[ 3150.423607] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 3150.423636] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0
```

I see the device at `/dev/block/sda` but I don't have any idea about mounting it manually. I was expecting `/dev/block/sda1` and `/dev/block/sda2`.

How do I manage those partitions?

Comment: Are you sure there are no files named sda1 and sda2 under /dev/block? You can use `mount` command-line tool  (try busybox's mount too) to mount those partitions.

Comment: I see /dev/block/sda, not /dev/block/sda1 or /dev/block/sda2
Same drive on linux is mounted fine.

Comment: Your kernel likely does not support ext3: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/46946/1465  What device and Android version do you have?

Comment: I have some partitions as ext4, so the kernel modules are fine. Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't fix the original issue.
I have just merged all the data in a single partition. I have no idea why the system can't mount the disk with two partitions.